# reflexion in a display custom attribute mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, system.reflection

I'm trying to create a custom attribute that display the value of property CountryText

```
[DisplayNameProperty("CountryText")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string CountryText { get; set; }
```

this the code of the attribute

```
namespace Registration.Front.Web.Validators
    {
        public class RegistrationDisplayNameAttribute:DisplayNameAttribute
        {
            private readonly PropertyInfo _proprtyInfo;
            public RegistrationDisplayNameAttribute(string resourceKey):base(resourceKey)
            {

            }

            public override string DisplayName
            {
                get
                {
                    if(_proprtyInfo==null)

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

How can i do the reflexion to obtain the value of the fild named `resourceKey` in my code of attribute??

Comment: You would need to get the `Sender` object into your constructor too, unfortunately this is impossible to do with an attribute as you need to use constant values

Answer (score -1):

Since it is impossible to pass instances to an attribure via constructor, (i.e the attributes are included in metadata at compile time, and then used via reflexion, you can see [Pass instance of Class as parameter to Attribute constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284807/pass-instance-of-class-as-parameter-to-attribute-constructor))

There is a work arround to pass the instance, and that is to do it in the constructor like that:

```
  public class Foo
  {
    [RegistrationDisplayNameAttribute("MyProp2")]
    public string MyProp { get; set; }

    public string MyProp2 { get; set; }


    public Foo()
    {
      var atts = this.GetType().GetCustomAttributes();
      foreach (var item in atts)
      {
        if (atts is RegistrationDisplayNameAttribute)
        {
          ((RegistrationDisplayNameAttribute)atts).Instance = this;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and in the DisplayName you do:

```
public override string DisplayName
{
  get
  {
    var property = Instance.GetType().GetProperty(DisplayNameValue);
    return property.GetValue(Instance, null) as string;
  }

}
```

I don't recommend such method :(

Comment: i dont use a system of resource file, i have my own system of ressource, so i need the reflexion to get the value o key name and after use my own system to get value

Comment: Whatever you are gonna use is not the issue here, the value of the resource key is in DisplayNameValue, you can use it howerver you wish, I don't know your context and what i posted is an example, you can change it and put it in your context, I repeat if you need the resourceKey value then it is in DisplayNameValue

Comment: i need the value of the property CountryText in my example