# Dynamic RegularExpression attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this form where there's a Postal Code field, in my ViewModel  it looks something like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$")]
public string PostalCode { get; set; }
```

That regular expression accepts 5 digits postal codes, but now I need to support other countries where they use 8, 4 or 6 digits postal codes.

I have those custom regex in a database, but I can't pass non-static variables to an attribute in this way:

```
[RegularExpression(MyCustomRegex)]
public string PostalCode { get; set; }
```

What can I do? I tried creating a custom attribute, but in some point I needed to pass a non-static parameter, which is not possible.

Should I use reflection? Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way may be to decouple the attribute from the regex.

```
public class PostalCodeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public interface IPostalCodeModel
{
    string PostalCode { get; }
}

public class UsModel : IPostalCodeModel
{
    [PostalCode(Country = "en-US")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}

public class GbModel : IPostalCodeModel
{
    [PostalCode(Country = "en-GB")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

Validator:

```
public class PostalCodeValidator
{
    private readonly IRegularExpressionService _regularExpressionService;

    public PostalCodeValidator(IRegularExpressionService regularExpressionService)
    {
        _regularExpressionService = regularExpressionService;
    }

    public bool IsValid(IPostalCodeModel model)
    {
        var postalCodeProperty = model.GetType().GetProperty("PostalCode");

        var attribute = postalCodeProperty.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(PostalCodeAttribute)) as PostalCodeAttribute;

        // Model doesn't implement PostalCodeAttribute
        if(attribute == null) return true;

        return ValidatePostalCode(_regularExpressionService, model, attribute.Country);
    }

    private static bool ValidatePostalCode(
        IRegularExpressionService regularExpressionService,
        IPostalCodeModel model,
        string country
    )
    {
        var regex = regularExpressionService.GetPostalCodeRegex(country);
        return Regex.IsMatch(model.PostalCode, regex);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the end I finally found a way to get all the data that I needed without passing it as a parameter, but if I wouldn't be able to do that I think this would be the best option.

Comment: Hi I know its a while back now but i am having exact the same problem. Would it be possible to share your solution you mentioned above please? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in several related questions (e.g. [Pass instance of Class as parameter to Attribute constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284807/pass-instance-of-class-as-parameter-to-attribute-constructor?rq=1) [Lambda expression in attribute constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809294/lambda-expression-in-attribute-constructor?rq=1)) only compile time literals are allowed as arguments for an attribute.

I did think of a workaround that may or may not work. The idea is to create a custom attribute class that derives from the regular expression attribute and that performs a regex lookup on construction and passes the result to its base.

**DISCLAIMER:** I haven't actually tested it (and am not planning on doing so ;-).

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class PostalCodeAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Func<string, string>> _resolverDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Func<string, string>>();
    private static string Resolve(string source)
    {
        Func<string, string> resolver = null;
        if (!_resolverDict.TryGetValue(source, out resolver))
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("No resolver for {0}", source));
        return resolver(source);
    }
    public static void RegisterResolver(string source, Func<string, string> resolver)
    {
        _resolverDict.AddOrUpdate(source, resolver, (s, c) => resolver);
    }

    static PostalCodeAttribute()
    {
        // necessary to enable client side validation
        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(PostalCodeAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
    }

    public PostalCodeAttribute(string patternSource)
        : base(Resolve(patternSource))
    {
    }
}

/// ...

public void SomeIntializer()
{
    PostalCodeAttribute.RegisterResolver("db_source", (s) => PostalCodeRegularExpressions.LookupFromDatabase());
}

public class SomeClassWithDataValidation
{
    [PostalCode("db_source")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

Note that this will only work, if registration of a matching resolver function is done before any of these attributes are instantiated.